# Eclipse cannot find class in JAR

Tags: java, eclipse

Weird thing is, I can call class `NetHttpTransport` but not `NetHttpRequest`. I tried to clean & build but nothing helped.

[image]

Edit: thanks for the answers, I just knew that it's possible to have private class in a package :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetHttpRequest class is defined with default access, so it is not accessible outside com.google.api.client.http.javanet package. NetHttpTransport is a public class, so you can access it from any package.

You can check out the sources from https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/javanet/NetHttpRequest.java

Answer (score 1):

[`NetHttpRequest`](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/com/google/api/client/javanet/NetHttpRequest.java?r=05b5d9dbb177dce691e824162cf8ad5d9fc0c24f) is a package private class. You can't access a non-public class outside of its package.

Comment: Its `final class NetHttpRequest extends LowLevelHttpRequest`, this is private?